# Amazon RDS replication with external slave

Tags: mysql, replication, external, rds

I've recently configured a replication with an external MySQL master and RDS as slave but now I need to reverse that config and use RDS as master and the other instance as slave. Actually I use a vpn and the other instance is outside AWS.

I changed the server host and password but I got this error:

> 141103 11:35:44 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Binary log is not open (server_errno=1236) 141103 11:35:44 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Binary log is not open', Error_code: 1236
>
> 141103 11:35:44 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.000007', position 284079763
>
> 141103 11:37:09 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed

Perhaps I didn't get the right log filename and postion? but I can't find them in to RDS

Thanks for your help!